# How to tell if a MacBook can be recovered from a liquid spill?

Tags: macbook-pro, damage

I have a user that spilled a glass of wine on their 2013 13" MacBook Pro. It stopped working. I tried drying it out for a few days before trying again but it won't turn on. Is there a systematic way to figure out whether there's any value to salvage here or if it's a total loss? Something I can do myself or is it better to make a trip to a Genius Bar near me?

Comment: I'm afraid all the wrong things were done so far, corrosion will add to the short-circuits.